# How to connect remote emulator to my Laptop?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, genymotion

Hi everyone,

I have Android studio running on a MacBook Pro, and Genymotion emulator running on Windows 10 PC.

Now I want to write code from my MacBook Pro and run it on the emulator.

Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: I think genymotion's free emulator  doesn't have enough control. Use this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) with default emulator

Comment: I can't use the default emulator, because i have an AMD pc.